# React Native App Icon Not Showing As Specified in Res Folder

Tags: android, react-native

I have been working with react native for quite a while. 
I am having this weird issue with the application icon. I am only targeting Android for now.

I have replaced the ic_launcher.png in all "android/app/src/main/res/mipmap-*" folders. After deploying the app on emulator or a real device the app icon is showing a black droid icon like the image link
[(Black droid icon instead of app icon)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v0oZf.png)
I tried this on actual devices too same issue.
Note: When i open the list of apps from phone settings the app icon is showing fine in the list of apps see image link
[(Icon showing fine in app list from android settings)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rxjdE.png)

Could anyone direct me what the issue might be? I tried cleaning and rebuilding. Also tried clearing all cache and reinstalling app. Also generation of signed apk has the same behavior.

Comment: Just wanted to know that, all replaced icons are of same size? If yes then please try cleaning the gradlew by firing "gradlew clean" command from your project/android directory and rerun react-native run-android. Hope it will help you.

Comment: I know this issue is old now.. but for anyone having the same issue here is what happened to me.
When the app was rolled out to customers the icon was showing fine. The issue only existed in our development phones. 
Also I didn't face this issue again in later apps made. Guess it was something very specific to that project.
Hope it doesn't show up again (fingers crossed)  :)